# How to fix the issue of mouse-pointer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, mouse-cursor, mousehover

I'm using PHP, jQuery, JavaScript, etc. for my website.
Now, requirement is a script in jQuery/JavaScript which will give alert to the user when the mouse-pointer is away from the tab in which webpage from my website is opened.

Can anyone help in this regard? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: what a horrible user experience concept, why would you ever need anything like this?

Comment: To handle all cases, i'd say it is not possible or maybe using some kind of server check (for multiple tabs)

Comment: @A.Wolff:Yes, we can make use of PHP for sever check in order to consider all the cases. But how to achieve the desired result is the biggest challenge for me now.

Comment: @charlietfl:Yes, this weird requirement has come to me from client and I've to do this thing quickly. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: Would suggest you tell client that doing things like this will cause users to avoid their site as it will cause all sorts of unexpected behavior and annoying alerts.

Comment: @charlietfl:Unfortuanately I can't tell this thing to client:) but anyhow I've to make this functionality workable on my website. Can you help me in this regard, please?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
$(document).focusout(function() { 
       alert("your out"); 
});
```

Comment: using mouseleave would avoid any children check as mouseleave event propagate through DOM. BTW, i think this answer is just one part of OP's issue

Comment: yeah your right... use .focusout() . That triggers perfect i think //I Edited above

Comment: ya, maybe focusout will be more appropriate here

Comment: @Cracker0dks:As per your answer I wrote a sample code to make the thing happen. It's happening to some extent too. But causing one issue I've to click the ok button in pop-up twice to close the pop-up. After clicking first time it has to close but it's not getting closed. For your reference I'm attaching a JS FIDDLE URL. You can copy this code in one file and run it on your machine, then you will come to know about the issue. JS Fiddle Link is : http://jsfiddle.net/xYE6b/

Comment: I get only one popup in chrome if i click the url bar for example.

Comment: @Cracker0dks:Have you clicked on Ok button and did it close after it. I tested in firefox btw. And on chrome it's not working at all.

Comment: @Cracker0dks:But on my machine I've to click the Ok button twice to close the pop-up in firefox and on chrome nothing is working. Would you please make the necessary changes to the code to make it runnable on all popular browsers and create a fiddle for it? btw Lots of Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I think [@Cracker0dks's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20266051/2567813) answer is the best way,

```
$(document).focusout(function() { 
       alert("your out"); 
});
```

If you want to track shortcut keys using `jquery keypress events`, you should know about the key codes of key board buttons. And alert user if they presses what combination of keys you want to track.

to know about key codes, visit this url http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000520.html

but If the user presses any short cut keys to minimize windows you can just show alert in the browser page only. After minimize user can't see your alert message.

You could also use it like in this fiddle **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GdPdQ/2/)**